# SQL query: return specific value in 2nd table, else return NULL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make a join on 2 tables - let's call them `CAT` and `DRINK`. What I'm trying to do is return only a specific "`Type`" from the `DRINK` table, else return `NULL` for that table. That said, I still want all rows from my `CAT` table.

So if the type of drink I'm trying to return is "`Milk`", the result of my query: -

```
Garfield    | Milk 
Tom         | Milk 
Hello Kitty | NULL
```

In the above example, Garfield and Tom have "`Milk`" in the `DRINK` table (they might also have some other values, like "`Wine`" or "`Beer`") and Hello Kitty does not have "`Milk`" (hence the `NULL`).

I've been trying to solve this doing some `UNION` or `UNION ALL` queries combined with a `WHERE` on "`Type`" (am I on the right path here?) but have had no luck.

Would anybody please be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is your friend.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you are looking for an Outer join: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: @Andrew Those pages (W3schools) have so many errors that I think that links to them should be removed as spam - from a professional site as SO.

Comment: @ypercube, I still think the links are useful.  W3 links are way easier to understand for beginners than MS's syntax pages.

Comment: @Sev09 I'd rather they spend extra time to learn the *correct* way, then spend less time to learn the *wrong* way.

Comment: @Sev09 Easier maybe, but it's easier to get misleading information, too, which is not good for beginners. And I wouldn't advise beginners to be reading the SQL-Server's syntax pages either. There are a lot of other good sites out there.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, I guess I've never really come across any misleading information.  I don't use them too much other than reminders of simple syntax I haven't used in a while.

Comment: @Sev09: Random page from there: [BETWEEN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) The example is totally screwed up, shows complete misunderstanding of `CHAR` columns and ordering. (the query will show no word starting with `'M`, except the 1-character `'M'` letter itself.) It also mentions nothing about lower/upper case letters. And cares not about alphabet other than ASCII (what if I use Spanish or an aplhabet, what will "between C and M" mean then?)

Comment: @ypercube, I gotcha.  That's definitely overlooked.

Answer (score 5):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT C.Cat, D.Drink
FROM CAT AS C
LEFT JOIN DRINK AS D
    ON C.CatId = D.CatId
    AND D.Drink = 'Milk'
```